# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 publishing to IIS as an application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I am publishing an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 site to IIS 7.5. When I publish it as a Web Site it works, but I have to have it have its own port (i.e. 8080). I want to have it just be an application under the default site, but when I do that it works, except that static files don't resolve (so I don't get my css or js files for example).

Comment: Have you tried to add app.UseStaticFiles(); in the Configure method in Startup?

Comment: Yes, I have app.UseStaticFiles(); in the Configure method in Startup.cs.